# Как найти общие элементы в сетах?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

Как найти общие элементы в сетах?

Но не только найти, а и узнать, какие именно элементы общие.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

Пример:

```
In [146]: a = set([1,2,3])

In [147]: b = set([3,4,5,2])

In [148]: res = a & b

In [149]: res
Out[149]: {2, 3}
```

или:

```
res = a.intersection(b)
```